# Vuetify - combobox badges with a removable button

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, combobox, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a combobox:

```html
<v-combobox
    v-model="selectedCategories"
    :items="attributeCategories"
    item-text="name"
    item-value="id"
    label="Category"
    multiple
    chips
    v-on:blur="changeCategory(selectedCategories)"
></v-combobox>
```

It's rendered like this:

[image]

I would like to add an `x` on each badge, so I can quickly remove it.

Is there a setting that I need to turn on?

In regular input type text, I can just add these props

- clear-icon="mdi-close-circle"
- clearable

Answer (score 1):

The `VComboBox`'s `selection` slot enables customizing the rendering of the selections. You could add a `VChip` with a `VIcon` child that re-selects the item when clicked (thus toggling its selection, and removing the chip):

```html
<v-combobox ⋯ chips>
  <template v-slot:selection="{ attrs, item, parent, selected }">
    <v-chip v-bind="attrs" :input-value="selected">
      <span class="pr-2">
        {{ item.name }}
      </span>
      <v-icon small @click="parent.selectItem(item)"> $delete </v-icon>
    </v-chip>
  </template>
</v-combobox>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vuetify-combobox-with-clearable-chips-5ewv7p?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FCategoryCombobox.vue)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve that by adding the `<v-icon>` inside `<v-chip>` in the `<v-slot>` template. I just created the working demo with the same data set you have in the screenshot mentioned above.

Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    items: ['Weather', 'Geo Location', 'Device', 'Date and Time', 'Product'],
    model: ['Weather', 'Geo Location', 'Device', 'Date and Time', 'Product']
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.5/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.5/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css"/>
<v-app id="inspire">
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-combobox
      v-model="model"
      :items="items"
      label="Category"
      multiple
      small-chips
    >
      <template v-slot:selection="{ item, parent }">
        <v-chip
          label
          small
        >
          <span class="pr-2">
            {{ item }}
          </span>
          <v-icon
            small
            @click="parent.selectItem(item)"
          >
            $delete
          </v-icon>
        </v-chip>
      </template>
    </v-combobox>
  </v-container>
</v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a **chips** props your `<v-combobox...>` - so depends on Vuetify version there are two props you should add:

- **deletable-chips** for Vuetify 2 according to [docs](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-combobox/#props-deletable-chips)

```
<v-combobox
  ...
  chips
  deletable-chips
/>
```

- **closable-chips** for Vuetify 3 according to [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-combobox/#props-closable-chips)

```
<v-combobox
  ...
  chips
  closable-chips
/>
```

Also there is **clearable** prop that adds clear button on the right that clear all chips via one click (works for both Vuetify versions):

```
<v-combobox
  ...
  clearable
/>
```